# Invalid tag in web.config file HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config

Built a c# web app in Visual Studio, installed it on the IIS server.  When I try to browse to it locally, I get 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - Error Code 0x8007000d, And I can't double click on any of the settings for that app in IIS, it complains about an error in the web.config.

If I remove the line below, I can double click the settings in IIS, but the page doesn't work, so I'm guessing I am missing a prerequisite or something related to this web.config tag, but I can't find it?

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

Comment: Did you install the [ASP.NET Core hosting package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Comment: That did it!   Thanks Mason!

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mason's response of

Did you install the ASP.NET Core hosting package? – mason

Fixed the issue